# How to use __doPostback in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I tried below code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "postback", "<script>$(document).ready( function() {__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PrintExcemptionsButton',''});</script>", false);
```

But the problem is, the code itself does not execute a postback and click the `PrintExcemptionsButton`

What I am trying to achieve is to induce is to click a button programatically using `__doPostback` method in c#,

Please help me out.

Comment: in my opinion is not such a good idea to put js code in the .cs file, I prefer to keep them in a separate JS file or at least put it in the .aspx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the `.click()` event on your button that would cause the postback you are searching for:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "postback", "<script>$(document).ready( function() {$('#" + PrintExcemptionsButton.ClientID + "').click()});</script>", false);
```

However I don't see the sense of this. You could simply call the `OnButtonClick()` function in your `Page_Load` function from codebehind.

Comment: Thank YOU !!! You saved my whole day searching, well it's hard to explain why i need to use this, i need to separate the codes of the PrintExcemptionsButton from the button where i put the code you gave me for it to work, because of databinding and response.end issue.

Answer (score -4):

```
 function btnAssignTrigger() {

 __doPostBack("<%=btnAssign.UniqueID %>", '');
}

<asp:Button ID="btnAssign" runat="server" Text="Assign" CausesValidation="false"                                                        OnClientClick="return btnAssignTrigger();" OnClick="btnAssign_Click" />
```

Use like this.

Comment: how will i use this? any explanaton would help./